# How to run the magento server code on my local system?

Tags: file, magento, server, installation, local

```
Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/7.0.30
```

Comment: What code is raising this error. If possible include this in your original post to add better background context to the question.

Comment: I have a Magento project and DB also...i downloaded it using FTP and put that project in htdocs and import the DB in PHPMyAdmin...and after in database under core_config_data table change the un_secure and secure base URLs to local URL's, next in app-->env folder-> changed database details to local....after i run the project but it was showing error like below............

Comment: Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/7.0.30

Comment: how can I run the server project in my local machine...? what steps I have to follow? please tell me....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your url rewrite is working on your server.